VIP's for servers connected to different subnets
In a VOIP system, I have two controllers (servers) in a dual homed setup, each controller with 2 network interfaces connected to 2 different subnets as below:
server 1:
ETH1: IP 10.20.30.10, netmask: 255.255.0.0, connected to LAN1 (10.20.x.x),
ETH2: IP 10.21.30.10, netmask: 255.255.0.0, connected to LAN2 (10.21.x.x).

server 2:
ETH1: IP 10.21.30.11, netmask: 255.255.0.0, connected to LAN2 (10.21.x.x),
ETH2: IP 10.20.30.11, netmask: 255.255.0.0, connected to LAN1 (10.20.x.x).

The problem is that I need to configure virtual IP for servers connections to LAN1 and a second VIP for the other 2 servers connections to LAN2, but then I have to select VIP's that can fit with both subnets, please advise VIP's to be used.

A (virtual) IP address cannot belong to multiple subnets (unless they overlap which kills routing).
Usually you'd assign one VIP shared between the hosts/servers for each subnet.
Another option is to use a loopback interface on each host, put the VIP on that - sharing across hosts and interfaces - and then use the hosts' physical interface addresses as gateways to the loopback VIP. Provided your servers work with that, you'd have to monitor that gateway addresses instead of the VIP and manipulate the routing in case of failing over.
